# Convert semi-colon separated codes in a column to their values SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know this goes against all DB normalization principals but I cannot change the design at this point.

I have a column that has values stored like this (SQL Server database):

```
5;26;31;49
```

There's another table that has translation for this values which looks like this:

```
Code   Value
-------------------
5      Some Value 1
26     Some Value 2
31     Some Value 3
49     Some Value 4
```

I need to convert the semi-colon delimited codes into their corresponding values and present these values as part of just 1 row, so what I want to see as a result is:

```
Some Value 1; Some Value 2; Some Value 3; Some Value 4
```

Does anyone have a solution for this puzzle?

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You might also put your efforts into fixing the data model.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff I tagged it with SQL. Any other tags I should use? Like I mentioned, though I understand it's a bad design, it cannot be changed at this point.

Comment: [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string_split if you are on SQLSERVER,that transpose row to a column.The result set can be used as a table and joined with any table in the DB for desired result.

```
declare @str VARCHAR(20)= '5;26;31;49'
 (SELECT VALUE FROM string_split(@str,';'));
```

When two tables are joined the result would look like the below,

```
 select tablB.value from 
 (SELECT VALUE as code FROM string_split(tableA.col,';')) transposed_table,
 tableB 
 where transposed_table.code = tableB.code
```

You may use cursor to loop through to transport the output to a string as below,

```
DECLARE @codevalues VARCHAR(max) = '';
DECLARE @codevalue VARCHAR(20)= '';

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
  select tablB.value+';' from 
  (SELECT VALUE as code FROM string_split(tableA.col,';')) transposed_table,
  tableB 
  where transposed_table.code = tableB.code;

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @codevalue
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
      set @codevalues = @codevalues+@codevalue;
      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @codevalue

END

CLOSE db_cursor
PRINT @codevalues;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

In the most recent versions of SQL Server, you can use `string_split()` and `string_agg()`:

```
select t.*, v.expanded
from t cross apply
     (select string_agg(c.value, ';') within group (order by charindex(c.code, t.codes) as expanded
      from string_split(t.codes, ';') join
           codes c
           on c.code = s.value
     ) v;
```

Comment: Glad to know about string_agg, this will alleviate developers from pain for pivoting dynamic columns.